# desktop height higher than monitor height. xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, hdmi, xrandr

settings and info:

xrandr -q outputs this info on my second monitor

```
HDMI-0 connected 1080x1920+3840+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm panning 1080x2160+3840+0 tracking 4920x2160+0+0 border 0/0/0/0
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1600x900      60.00
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x800      59.81
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

the command I'm currently using at startup is:

```
xrandr --output DP-4 --primary &
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --right-of DP-4 --rotate left --auto &
```

what's going on:

I have a secondary monitor, hdmi-0, which is rotated to be tall.

the desktop is too tall for the monitor, resulting in scrolling along the y-axis.

I am unsure of how to fix this. this seems to be a new problem (when I set up this computer this behavior wasn't present -- but now: I have no idea what caused it)

from what I'm reading it's set to be 1920x1080 as a screen, but the desktop is 1080x2160... which is not the native resolution of the monitor... which I don't read in the list under xrandr -q... and if i try to set it with --mode 1080x2160... it can not find that mode. trying the other modes it scales in awkwardly... when i set it to 1920x1080... it scrolls along the y-axix (the 1920 distance... which isn't 1920 but 2160 instead...)

so how do I set the desktop to be in sync with the monitor resolution 1920x1080?

what the what?

also the monitor is:

Samsung SH650 Series 27 inch FHD 1920x1080

if that's important.

Comment: if i move the mouse to the bottom of the screen, it scrolls - hiding the top bar... if i move the mouse to the top of the screen - it reappears. this doesn't happen going left and right. the desktop is taller than the monitor. how do I fix that - is what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by going to the nvida-settings gui

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

then going to Xserver display configuration > advanced .

and futzing with the settings there... ended up resetting it by detecting displays, and now it works as expected (no panning, desktop is the same size as monitor now)